# Google calendar v3 Push notifications "missing"

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps-marketplace

We are using Google Calendar v3 Push Notifications for around 250 users.

We are looking to increase this number to 1000 soon.

We have noticed that generally the notifications are working however we are not fully convinced on the reliability.

Because of this we have a "24 hour" poll of each users calendar in the event that there has not been a notification received.

Now if all is working - there should be no calendar changes that we have not been "notified" of.

However... this is not the case - we have 1 or 2 users a day where a notification has not been received...

Has anybody else observed this??  There is no way to know if a notification has not been sent from Google???

I would like to do away with polling but this is not reliable enough yet.

Ideally Google would provide a queryable list of changed calendars rather than using notifications which if missed/fail for some reason are gone for good.

Any thoughts/experiences would be appreciated on this,

Paul C

Comment: Yes, there is a disclaimer about it at the bottom of: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push Is one request a day for making sure there were no changes going to cause you quota issues? Are you using sync tokens?

Comment: Thanks luc - that is very disappointing...  So given that we can't rely on notifications there is really no point in using them.  Looks like we will need to go back to polling on a timed basis.  Yes we have been using Sync tokens.  The issue we face is that we are synchronising calendars and at any given point in time with this limitation we can't guarantee that the calendars are in sync.  What have you done??

Comment: Hi PNC, I disagree that this is black and white. Push gives you a very instant way of knowing that there is something new so there are no delays caused by polling intervals. Re-polling once a day just to make sure you missed nothing is a safety net for the cases of missed pushes (you could also for example miss pushes because the device was offline and did not reconnect in time before the delivery timed out). It really depends on what kind of app you are writing but for example polling causes radio on phones to be awake unnecessarily, eats up quota, etc...

Comment: Hi Luc, thanks for your thoughts.  Our App provides enterprise level calendar integration (on a centralised server)- so potentially 1000+ calendars for a client.  The push concept is great but at the moment our users are conditioned to a 10 minute delay for updates so we're not selling instant to them.  Polling is 100% reliable - in that if a change has happened to Google Calendar we will know about it.  Given that a missed push should be rare we will continue with a hybrid approach - maybe push plus 2 hour poll.  The quota limitations mean that we can't poll every 10 minutes.